zenith angle with getsolarposition
So this is a quick question.
I made a program that calculates the zenith angels for a specific day.
zenith angle code
When I print these angles I get the following:
Results of the code
I just want to have the angels so I can use them. What do I need to change in my code so that I don't have the other text like "Name: apparent_zenith, dtype: float64 2024-05-15 18:00:00+02:00"
I don't know what I have to change because I didn't code the text that I don't want

Your desired angle is the last element of the list, just use print(angle[-1]),

You should really put the code and output into the question as text rather than images.

In your code angle is actually a pandas Series object that contains one value.  When you print a pandas Series object, you get information about the whole object, which includes the name, timestamp/index and data type.
To print only the values without the extra info, you can use:
print(angle.values)

The way you have written the program you know there is only one value in each angle object, so you can tell it to print only the first value:
print(angle.values[0])

